# Dev Demon Updater error

Tags: devdemon-updater

just used Dev Demons' Updater for the first time (update 2.6.1 to 2.7.2) I got a not completed message and them the following: AJAX request failed.

However when I look at the current version running its updated. But when I go the Updater CP I see the "Ajax Request Failed" when I click on the "Show Response" link I get:

{"error":"
Error Number: 1054</p>\n\n

Unknown column 'csrf_exempt' in 'field list'</p>\n\n

SELECT `class`, `method`, `csrf_exempt`\nFROM (`exp_actions`)\nWHERE `action_id` = '44'</p>\n\n

Filename: libraries/Actions.php</p>\n\n

Line Number: 82</p>"}

When I go to the EE CP I get this message: Your ExpressionEngine installation’s version (2.6.1) is not consistent with the reported version (2.7.3). Please update your installation of ExpressionEngine again.

[image]

Comment: In your `exp_actions` table, what method and class is action_id 44?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution that I've found for this in the past, is to go into your /system/expressionengine/config/config.php file and change the version number in there back to 2.6.1 and then re-run the upgrade using updater.

This would reapply the update and should resolve the problem for you.

Comment: I looked at the config file it had 261 as the version. Still got the error.

Comment: I reverted my config version back to 255 and re-ran the 2.9.2 upgrade, this fixed my issue. Thanks