# Updater Error Number: 1054

Tags: ee2-upgrades

I've just run the updater from 2.5.5 to 2.9.0 and have gotten:

```
{"error":"
Error Number: 1054\n\n

Unknown column 'csrf_exempt' in 'field list'\n\n

UPDATE `exp_actions` SET `csrf_exempt` = 1 WHERE `class` = 'Search' AND `method` = 'do_search'\n\n

Filename: \/Daves's Sites\/site_name\/system\/expressionengine\/modules\/search\/upd.search.php\n\n

Line Number: 185"}
```

Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Related? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19687/dev-demon-updater-error

Answer (score 1):

A [bug](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20533/if-updating-from-2.1.5-or-older-and-blogger-module-is-installed-mysql-error)?

For now, fix this by yourself.

```
ALTER TABLE exp_actions ADD `csrf_exempt` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL default 0
```